# Chart property showValues not working in Fusion Charts zoomline chart

Tags: javascript, vue.js, fusioncharts

I cannot find a way to make `showValues: '1'` show the data plot values in a *zoomline* graphic with Fusion Charts.

You see and try it in this *fiddle*: http://jsfiddle.net/60oeahc1/4/

**¿Is there a way to make it work for *zoomline* charts?**

The thing is that with a *line* chart is working: http://jsfiddle.net/z0xutjhL/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per your query, since zoomline features large data , using showValue would overlap the data value text which in turn will result in poor visualization. Hence, It will not be possible to use showValue here.

Comment: Another related question to zoomline graphics. ¿Is it posible to draw lines the same as splined charts do? I would like to see curves instead of straight lines.

Comment: If you have date/time in the x-axis use our time-series chart, where you can have the smooth line. You can check the below link for reference : https://www.fusioncharts.com/fusiontime/examples/spline-plot-with-time-axis?framework=javascript

Comment: Hi again, I'm facing another possible related problem with _zoomline_ chart type.
Is it posible that responsiveness is not working with this type of chart?
Fiddle for _zoomline_ (http://jsfiddle.net/jt7L9fdx/) and fiddle for time-series chart (https://jsfiddle.net/xrg3q9uo/), in both cases using a width of 100%

Comment: @daniegarcia254 I am sorry for the late reply, yes there was a bug in 3.17.0 and it's fixed in 3.18.0, you can reload the fiddle again it should work

Comment: Still not working _showValues_ with _zoomline_ chart in 3.18.0: http://jsfiddle.net/60oeahc1/4/